# Dynamic script loading

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm busy on a project and I have some extra javascript files that need to be loaded when the project is running. Now for that I have created the code below:

```
var script = _thisIframe.contentDocument.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'main.js?' + Math.random();

_thisIframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(script);
```

This code works fine in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera IE9 and IE8. But it doens't in IE7
Here I get the following error:

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'createElement': object is null or undefined`

The error is created when it does the createElement line.

I searched for this type of error, but I didn't find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentDocument` isn't supported in IE7, or more specifically, you get that error because `contentDocument` is not a property of `_thisIframe` and therefore returning `undefined`, which of course has no `createElement()` method.

Use `contentWindow.document` for IE7  support.

An easy way to get the correct property is to exploit the `||` logical operator and its [short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) nature, as well as JavaScript returning the last evaluated value in a condition (most times the *truthy* operand).

```
var doc = _thisIframe.contentDocument || _thisIframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Comment: Ow yeah. That was the problem. Thanks!